# Kubernetes - is it ok to have 1 Control Plane and 1 worker Node for dev/test purposes?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, containers, azure-aks

we need to initiate Kubernetes cluster and start our development.
Is it OK to have 1 master Control Plane node and 1 worker node with our containers to start the development?
We can afford for services to be unavailable in case of upgrades, scaling and so on, I've just worried if I am lacking some more important info.
I was planning to have 8CPUs and 64 GB since that are the similar resources which we have on one of our VMs without containers with the same apps.

We will deploy cluster with Azure Kubernetes Service.
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, you can also have single node clusters. Just as you said, that means if one node goes down, the cluster is unavailable.

Comment: thanks for answer, so just to be clear - it means I need to have at least one master and one node cluster, I cannot have both of them (control plane and worker) at one node? Thanks

Comment: No, you can definitely do that. I don't know if AKS specifically lets you but Kubernetes doesn't care :)

Comment: Both minikube and kind (desktop-oriented developer-cluster tools) run a single "node" that's both a master and a worker.